# How to display img with xml and xsl

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I'm new in learn xml and xsl, well I have a problem, when I'm trying to show the images of my xml code using xsl the images keep hidden and the images are in the same folder with the xml and xsl files, I only see the td of the table empty and I didn't found a solution what work in my code because I'm new and the problems were different, I'm so confused in what I should to do or change, I will accept the tips very grateful

This is my xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="sector.xsl"?>
<sectors>
<sector>
<name>Simon bolivar</name>
<jp>
<img src="park.jpg"/>
</jp>
</sector>
<sector>
<name>Quillan</name>
<jp>
<img src="flowers.jpg"/>
</jp>
</sector>
<sector>
<name>Tisaleo</name>
<jp>
<img src="forest.jpg"/>
</jp>
</sector>
<sector>
<name>Quisapincha</name>
<jp>
<img src="mountain.jpg"/>
</jp>
</sector>
<sector>
<name>Pinllo</name>
<jpg>
<img src="river.jpg"/>
</jpg>
</sector>
</sectors>
```

this is my xsl code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
<body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Photo</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="sectors/sector">
      <tr>
        <td class="name"><xsl:value-of select="name" /></td>  
        <td><img src="{img/@src}" /></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: It seems your XSLT is working perfectly, I checked in oxygen. check if your images are accessible resources?

Answer (score 1):

The path to the `src` property is `jp/img/@src` so you should replace:

`src="{img/@src}"`

with:

`src="{jp/img/@src}"`

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have different tags in selector `jp` and `jpg`. Use below code will give you all image names

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <body>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Photo</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="sectors/sector">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="name">
                            <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="string-length(jp/img/@src) &gt; 0">
                                    <img src="{jp/img/@src}"/>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:otherwise>
                                    <img src="{jpg/img/@src}"/>
                                </xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

result is

```
<html>
 <body>
  <table>
     <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Photo</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td class="name">Simon bolivar</td>
        <td><img src="park.jpg"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td class="name">Quillan</td>
        <td><img src="flowers.jpg"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td class="name">Tisaleo</td>
        <td><img src="forest.png"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td class="name">Quisapincha</td>
        <td><img src="mountain.jpg"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td class="name">Pinllo</td>
        <td><img src="river.jpg"></td>
     </tr>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
```